# Two(?)-book series about dragons, two sisters, a wizard, and time travel

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I'm pretty sure this was a relatively modern book. The covers of the books were weirdly live action, I think.

Anyway, it's about two sisters who live in this glade and are protecting the last(?) dragon from an evil king. There's another male character, maybe, but I hardly remember him except for the fact he got branded on his face. At some point they take their dragon and go live with a wizard. The evil king finds them, and the wizard hides them by putting them forward in time, except it messes up and the littlest sister ends up getting separated.

So while the other group was in the far future for like an hour, she was stuck in the past for years with a different wizard. She learns to talk to animals and lives in the woods and stuff and actually ends up spending so much time in the past she becomes the older sister. She was really sad the whole time, and she forgets how to talk to animals at the end because she's so sad.

I remember thinking it was super dark for a children's book but it seemed good so I'm looking to find it again.

Comment: while I feel like this is Eragon

Comment: @someoneuseless not Eragon, there are no sisters, and no time travel involved

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out for myself. The series is *[Shadow of the Dragon](http://www.kateohearn.com/books/shadow-of-the-dragon/)* by Kate O'Hearn, it is a two book series, and oh boy did I forget the entire plot. My child self must be ashamed of me.

Summary of *Kira*:

> Kira is twelve and strong willed. The daughter of a retired dragon knight, she yearns for adventure and dreams of following in her father’s footsteps astride her own magnificent mount.
>
> But this can never happen. According to the laws of the kingdom, all girls must be married by the age of thirteen. Kira hates it, but being a girl, she has no choice.
>
> When war comes to the kingdom, Lord Dorcon and his knights arrive at her home to take her father, mother and brother, Dane, to the palace to serve the king. Kira and her sisters are to go to Lasser Commons – the most notorious prison in the land. Their only crime? Being unmarried girls.
>
> In a whirl of destruction and fire, Kira and her younger sister, Elspeth, manage to escape. But deep in her heart, Kira knows the real fight is just beginning. She and Elspeth are on the run and being hunted down by Lord Dorcon. When they are caught, they are to be executed.
>
> To stand a chance ever seeing her family again and to protect the life of her younger sister, Kira will need every bit of will power she can find.
>
> Let the battle commence…

Summary of *Elspeth*:

> One day, a young girl astride a twin-tailed dragon will destroy the monarchy and change the world for ever…
>
> Kira and Elspeth have already broken FIRST LAW many times over. Now outlawed and running for their lives they are determined to stand amongst the men and fight the unjust FIRST LAW that binds the kingdom. But cruel Lord Dorcon still stands in their way and the heat of his chase is stronger than ever.
>
> Strong and determined, Kira has done all that she can to protect and shield her younger sister. But now it’s time for Elspeth to grow up. When Paradon’s muddled magic separates the girls and sends them travelling through time to different eras, new challenges and terrifying threats await the sisters. Especially to Elspeth, left all alone to navigate a past world long before the rule of King Ardon and FIRST LAW. And all the while in a strange, alien world of the future, Kira must find a way to get back to Elspeth and reunite her family once again.
>
> A prophecy to fulfil. A cruel monarchy to upend.
> The battle continues…

Comment: You seem to have lost your original login; check out [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts so you can accept this answer.

Comment: And, once you merge your accounts, you can self-accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. :)